# Fastest way to append sequence objects in loop

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a for loop within which I get an `Seq[Seq[(String,Int)]]` for every run.  I have the usual way of running through the `Seq[Seq[(String,Int)]]` to get every `Seq[(String,Int)]` and then append it to a `ListBuffer[Seq[String,Int]]`.

Here is the following code:

```
var lis; //Seq[Seq[Tuple2(String,Int)]]
var matches = new ListBuffer[(String,Int)]

someLoop.foreach(k=>
  // someLoop gives lis object on evry run,
  // and that needs to be added to matches list
  lis.foreach(j => matches.appendAll(j))  
)
```

Is there better way to do this process without running through `Seq[Seq[String,Int]]` loop, say directly adding all the seq objects from the `Seq` to the `ListBuffer`?

I tried the `++` operator, by adding `matches` and `lis` directly. It didn't work either. I use Scala 2.10.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
matches.appendAll(lis.flatten)
```

This way you can avoid the mutable `ListBuffer` at all. `lis.flatten` will be the `Seq[(String, Int)]`. So you can shorten your code like this:

```
val lis = ... //whatever that is Seq[Seq[(String, Int)]]
val flatLis = lis.flatten // Seq[(String, Int)]
```

Avoid `var`'s and mutable structures like `ListBuffer` as much as you can

Comment: Actually `appendAll` [is no different from `++=`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/BufferLike.scala#L147)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to append to an empty `ListBuffer`, just create it directly:

```
import collection.breakOut

val matches: ListBuffer[(String,Int)] =
  lis.flatten(breakOut)
```

`breakOut` is the magic here.  Calling `flatten` on a `Seq[Seq[T]]` would usually create a `Seq[T]` that you'd then have to convert to a `ListBuffer`.  Using `breakOut` causes it to look at the expected output type and build that kind of collection instead.

Of course... You were only using `ListBuffer` for mutability anyway, so a `Seq[T]` is probably *exactly* what you really want.  In which case, just let the inferencer do its thing:

```
val matches = lis.flatten
```